# PHP/Genesis : Advanced Custom Fields in Genesis Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I'm trying to create a page that pulls up a custom post type (team) and the corresponding advanced custom fields and displays them on the template team page. I'm doing this in Genesis by merging one piece of code made for Wordpress (non-genesis) following this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/creating-meet-team-page-wordpress/).

I made some progress but I got stuck at the advanced custom fields. For example, `<?php the_title(); ?>` actually calls the PAGE title, instead of the Custom Post's Title. And the other fields (position, telephone, etc) aren't working - they're not being called at all. I'm sure it's an issue in how I merged this code with the Genesis.

```
<?php
/**
 * This file adds the city team template to any Genesis 2.0+ Theme.
 *
 * @author Jim Thornton
 * @package InboundFound
 * @subpackage Customizations
 */ 

/*
Template Name: Team
*/
?>

<?php
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'your_custom_loop' );

function your_custom_loop() { 


                    // Get 'team' posts
                    $team_posts = get_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => 'team',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Unlimited posts
                        'orderby' => 'title', // Order alphabetically by name
                    ) );

                    if ( $team_posts ):
                    ?>
                    <section class="row profiles">
                        <div class="intro">
                            <h2>Meet The Team</h2>
                            <p class="lead"></p>
                        </div>

                        <?php 
                        foreach ( $team_posts as $post ): 
                        setup_postdata($post);

                        // Resize and CDNize thumbnails using Automattic Photon service
                        $thumb_src = null;
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
                            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'team-thumb' );
                            $thumb_src = $src[0];
                        }
                        ?>
                        <article class="col-sm-6 profile">
                            <div class="profile-header">
                                <?php if ( $thumb_src ): ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $thumb_src; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>, <?php the_field('team_position'); ?>" class="img-circle">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="profile-content">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p class="lead position"><?php the_field('team_position'); ?></p>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="profile-footer">
                                <a href="tel:<?php the_field('team_phone'); ?>"><i class="icon-mobile-phone"></i></a>
                                <a href="mailto:<?php echo antispambot( get_field('team_email') ); ?>"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a>
                                <?php if ( $twitter = get_field('team_twitter') ): ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $twitter; ?>"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if ( $linkedin = get_field('team_linkedin') ): ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $linkedin; ?>"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </article><!-- /.profile -->
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </section><!-- /.row -->
                    <?php endif; 

}

genesis();
```

Answer (score 0):

"You must pass a reference to the global $post variable, otherwise functions like the_title() don't work properly."

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata#Parameters